# need to make salesforce app available in multiple language

Tags: appexchange, translation

I want to make my appexchange app available in multiple language like Spanish, dutch etc. so that depend on the language of the user they can access the app.

Is it possible in any way..

any help will be appreciated.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Translation Workbench is most useful feature of salesforce to provide multiple language support. It is available under `Administration Setup | Translation Workbench`. It is not enable by default you need to enable it from `Administration Setup | Translation Workbench > Translation settings`

It can be set to two levels:

- Org level
- User level

By translation workbench you can add new language available in pick list and then define custom label in that language. Which can be used on visual force page and Apex classes.

On VF page you can set language as:

```
<apex:page language="{!userSpecificlanguage}">
```

More details [here](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_wbench.htm)

Comment: Thanks much for the help, actually I am working on a app that is an appexchange product and i want it to available in multiple languages. I enable the Translation workbench but VF pages and class remain in english..

Answer (score 1):

Use **Translation Workbench** under **Setup**

Comment: Can you expand on that?